# Transform 3D numpy array in boolean 2D numpy array with nonzero condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Imagine we have the following 3D array:

```
[[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]],

 [[1, 2, 1],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [4, 2, 1]],

 [[0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 3],
 [0, 0, 0]]]
```

I want to reduce the dimension of the array and obtain True or False whenever each element in axis=2 is different or equal to [0, 0, 0], respectively.

Desired 2D output for the previous example array:

```
[[False, False, False]
 [True, False, True],
 [False, True, False]]
```

We pass from 3x3x3 int/float array to a 3x3 boolean array.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```py
print(arr[:, :, 1] != 0)  # 1 means second column, change to 0 for first, 2 for third column
```

Prints:

```
[[False False False]
 [ True False  True]
 [False  True False]]
```

---

**Note:** I used basing [numpy indexing of ndarray](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html). `[:, :, 1]` means that I want values from every 2D matrix, every row and second (1) column. Then compare these values to `0` to obtain boolean matrix.

Comment: It did not work :(

Comment: @Janikas Can you explain more? What did not work?

Comment: Sorry, my bad! It worked! :)

Comment: It would be nice if you explain how this works. To the best of my knowledge `arr[:, :, 1]` just takes the element at position 1 for each array at axis 2

Comment: @DaniMesejo Yes, I added short explanation.

Comment: But if you change [1, 2, 1] to [1, 0, 1] in the original array the proposed approach is going to return True, but [1, 0, 1] is different from [0, 0, 0]

Comment: @DaniMesejo I've understood the OP wants to compare all values from the second column of the 3d-array, in this case [0 0 0], [2 0 2], [0 1 0]

Comment: Apologies if I'm confused but in the question is written *is different or equal to [0, 0, 0],* so I thought the OP wanted to compare each element of the 2d matrix with [0, 0, 0],

Comment: @DaniMesejo Might be I've got it wrong :) Let's see if this answer is what OP wants...

Comment: I think OP wants to compare to [0,0,0] and **reduce** with `any`. The example makes it give the same result on each slice (I might also be wrong)

Answer (score 2):

IIUC you want to compare the last dimension to [0,0,0], returning False if all values are different, True otherwise.

Assuming `a` the 3D array:

```
out = (a != [0,0,0]).any(2)
```

Alternative:

```
out = ~(a == [0,0,0]).all(2)
```

Output:

```
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True, False,  True],
       [False,  True, False]])
```

Comment: `(test != [0,0,0]).all(2)` should also work. I believe the notion of *`each element` different* needs to be addressed by `all` rather than `any`

Comment: @onyambu yes could be, the example is unfortunately ambiguous (all zero or all non-zero)

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([
    [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
    ],

    [
        [1, 2, 1],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [4, 2, 1],
    ],

    [
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 1, 3],
        [0, 0, 0],
    ]
])

answer = (arr != 0).any(axis=2)

print(answer)
# [[False False False]
#  [ True False  True]
#  [False  True False]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 >>> test = [[[0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [0, 0, 0]],

 [[1, 2, 1],
 [0, 0, 0],
 [4, 2, 1]],

 [[0, 0, 0],
 [1, 1, 3],
 [0, 0, 0]]]
 >>> [[not ee == [0, 0, 0] for ee in e] for e in test]
```

Comment: I used list instead of numpy array. You can convert the numpy array to list first by "test.tolist()"